# Highcharts Multiple Series Drilldown to Multiple Series - only works for the last group in the series

Tags: highcharts, drilldown

I'm probably doing something dumb, but haven't found my error.

My main chart shows annual growth in headcount for each of three products.  Drilling down into any product should show me headcount growth for each job type in that product..

The drill down works, but only for Product C. It doesn't work for the first two groups (Product A and B).

Here's my jFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/rufustfirefly/mzc6Lvsw/1/

Code below:

```
Highcharts.chart('container', {
    chart: {
        type: 'column'
    },
    title: {
        text: 'Headcount By Product'
    },
    subtitle: {
        text: '2017 - 2021'
    },
    accessibility: {
        announceNewData: {
            enabled: true
        }
    },
    xAxis: {
        type: "category",
        crosshair: true
    },
    yAxis: {
        title: {
            text: 'Headcount'
        }

    },
    legend: {
        enabled: true
    },
    plotOptions: {
        series: {
            borderWidth: 0,
            dataLabels: {
                enabled: false,
                format: '{point.y:.0f}'
            }
        }
    },

    tooltip: {
        headerFormat: '<span style="font-size:11px">{point.key}</span><br>',
        pointFormat: '<span style="color:{point.color}">{series.name}</span>: <b>{point.y:.0f}</b><br/>',
        shared: true,
        useHTML: true
    },

    series: [
        {
            name: "2017",
            colorByPoint: false,
            data: [
                {
                    name: "Product A",
                    y: 3,
                    drilldown: "Product A 2017"
                },
                {
                    name: "Product B",
                    y: 3,
                    drilldown: "Product B 2017"
                },
                {
                    name: "Product C",
                    y: 4,
                    drilldown: "Product C 2017"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            name: "2018",
            colorByPoint: false,
            data: [
                {
                    name: "Product A",
                    y: 9,
                    drilldown: "Product A 2018"
                },
                {
                    name: "Product B",
                    y: 11,
                    drilldown: "Product B 2018"
                },
                {
                    name: "Product C",
                    y: 15,
                    drilldown: "Product C 2018"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            name: "2019",
            colorByPoint: false,
            data: [
                {
                    name: "Product A",
                    y: 15,
                    drilldown: "Product A 2019"
                },
                {
                    name: "Product B",
                    y: 15,
                    drilldown: "Product B 2019"
                },
                {
                    name: "Product C",
                    y: 15,
                    drilldown: "Product C 2019"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            name: "2020",
            colorByPoint: false,
            data: [
                {
                    name: "Product A",
                    y: 19,
                    drilldown: "Product A 2020"
                },
                {
                    name: "Product B",
                    y: 15,
                    drilldown: "Product B 2020"
                },
                {
                    name: "Product C",
                    y: 16,
                    drilldown: "Product C 2020"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            name: "2021",
            colorByPoint: false,
            data: [
                {
                    name: "Product A",
                    y: 19,
                    drilldown: "Product A 2021"
                },
                {
                    name: "Product B",
                    y: 15,
                    drilldown: "Product B 2021"
                },
                {
                    name: "Product C",
                    y: 16,
                    drilldown: "Product C 2021"
                }
            ]
        }
    ],
    drilldown: {
        allowPointDrilldown: false,
        series: [
            {
                name: "2017",
                id: "Product A 2017",
                data: [
                    ["Product Manager",1],
                    ["Business Analyst",0],
                    ["Developer",1],
                    ["QE",1 ]
                ],
                id: "Product B 2017",
                data: [
                    ["Product Manager",1],
                    ["Business Analyst",0],
                    ["Developer",1],
                    ["QE",0 ]
                ],
                id: "Product C 2017",
                data: [
                    ["Product Manager",1],
                    ["Business Analyst",1],
                    ["Developer",1],
                    ["QE",1 ]
                ]
            },
            {
                name: "2018",
                id: "Product A 2018",
                data: [
                    ["Product Manager",1],
                    ["Business Analyst",2],
                    ["Developer",4],
                    ["QE",2 ]
                ],
                id: "Product B 2018",
                data: [
                    ["Product Manager",1],
                    ["Business Analyst",1],
                    ["Developer",6],
                    ["QE",3 ]
                ],
                id: "Product C 2018",
                data: [
                    ["Product Manager",1],
                    ["Business Analyst",2],
                    ["Developer",8],
                    ["QE",4 ]
                ]
            },
            {
                name: "2019",
                id: "Product A 2019",
                data: [
                    ["Product Manager",1],
                    ["Business Analyst",2],
                    ["Developer",8],
                    ["QE",4 ]
                ],
                id: "Product B 2019",
                data: [
                    ["Product Manager",1],
                    ["Business Analyst",2],
                    ["Developer",8],
                    ["QE",4 ]
                ],
                id: "Product C 2019",
                data: [
                    ["Product Manager",1],
                    ["Business Analyst",3],
                    ["Developer",8],
                    ["QE",3 ]
                ]
            },
            {
                name: "2020",
                id: "Product A 2020",
                data: [
                    ["Product Manager",1],
                    ["Business Analyst",2],
                    ["Developer",10],
                    ["QE",6 ]
                ],
                id: "Product B 2020",
                data: [
                    ["Product Manager",1],
                    ["Business Analyst",2],
                    ["Developer",8],
                    ["QE",4 ]
                ],
                id: "Product C 2020",
                data: [
                    ["Product Manager",1],
                    ["Business Analyst",3],
                    ["Developer",8],
                    ["QE",4 ]
                ]
            },
            {
                name: "2021",
                id: "Product A 2021",
                data: [
                    ["Product Manager",1],
                    ["Business Analyst",2],
                    ["Developer",10],
                    ["QE",6 ]
                ],
                id: "Product B 2021",
                data: [
                    ["Product Manager",1],
                    ["Business Analyst",2],
                    ["Developer",8],
                    ["QE",4 ]
                ],
                id: "Product C 2021",
                data: [
                    ["Product Manager",1],
                    ["Business Analyst",3],
                    ["Developer",8],
                    ["QE",4 ]
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to define each drilldown series as a separate series object:

```
        {
            name: "2017",
            id: "Product A 2017",
            data: [
                ["Product Manager",1],
                ["Business Analyst",0],
                ["Developer",1],
                ["QE",1 ]
            ],
            id: "Product B 2017",
            data: [
                ["Product Manager",1],
                ["Business Analyst",0],
                ["Developer",1],
                ["QE",0 ]
            ],
            id: "Product C 2017",
            data: [
                ["Product Manager",1],
                ["Business Analyst",1],
                ["Developer",1],
                ["QE",1 ]
            ]
        },
```

transform to:

```
{
        name: "2017",
        id: "Product A 2017",
        data: [
          ["Product Manager", 1],
          ["Business Analyst", 0],
          ["Developer", 1],
          ["QE", 1]
        ],
      },
      {
        id: "Product B 2017",
        data: [
          ["Product Manager", 1],
          ["Business Analyst", 0],
          ["Developer", 1],
          ["QE", 0]
        ],
      }, {
        id: "Product C 2017",
        data: [
          ["Product Manager", 1],
          ["Business Analyst", 1],
          ["Developer", 1],
          ["QE", 1]
        ]
      }
```

Simplified demo: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/yb5760az/

Comment: Perfect - exactly what I was trying to do!  Thank you!